# dynamically create/call variables in python3

Tags: python-3.x

Hello everyone is there a better way to dynamically create/call variables, I'm trying to create a structural parser that will read the object data in a block and create those objects as variables dynamically as they are discovered.

This is and example of my current method, but it feels like I'm going about this wrong.

```
>>> VAR="VAR2"
>>> class item():
...     pass
... 
>>> newitem=item()
>>> exec('newitem.'+VAR+'=\''+'hello'+'\'')
>>> newitem.VAR2
'hello'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
setattr(object, attribute_name, value)
```

So, for example, `setattr(a, "pancakes", "syrup")` is (more or less) the same as `a.pancakes = "syrup"`

So, you can use `setattr(newitem, VAR, "hello")` to make `newitem.VAR2` become "hello".

Answer (score 4):

I think you're on the right track for dynamically creating variables, although I would question why you're not using a hashmap. Why not do

```
newitem = {}
newitem[VAR] = 'hello'
```

Try to stay away from the eval statement as much as possible because you have to adjust for "python injection". i.e. VAR could include a "'" which might cause invalid code. It's much easier to just use regular Python constructs when possible

Comment: yeah this is probably the more saner way of doing things, thanks.